# Export Calendar .ics not auto-refreshing, event times off

Tags: calendar, export

Good Morning,

I want to set up the export calendar function to allow a user to type in a URL into their Google Calendar, then automatically stay up-to-date as new users add to my non-profit's events calendar.

After reviewing [document](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/icalendar/) I have altered the example text (see below), but found that whether I download the .ics file directly, or whether I ask Google Calendar to add by URL where the revised text is located (http://mygatewayarts.org/calendar/export), that

1) the link is not active: the calendar does not include the latest information days later.

2) Despite setting the calendar to start today, I see some past recurring events, but certain one-time events do not.

3) Some event times are incorrectly listed.

Would you propose any tips or alternatives to the example text? Is this the best way to go about it?

4) Lastly, it'd be helpful as well if the descriptor text could link to the event detail page.

```
{exp:calendar:icalendar
    orderby="title"
    sort="asc"
    date_range_start="today"
    show_years="5"
    dynamic="off"
}
{/exp:calendar:icalendar}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't use this in conjunction with Solspace's Calendar, I've found [Easy iCalendar](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/easy-icalendar) to be a reliable method for generating content in that format; perhaps you can roll your own template using other Calendar tags?

Comment: Thanks Nick. I really appreciate your feedback. I'm surprised that this whole auto-add by .ics (feed) issue hasn't already been addressed. I'll check out Easy Calendar.

Comment: iCal format needs a SEQUENCE:X tag if you ever change/update a entry. i made Reevision addon for this.